# Python returns the same value for raising to a negative fraction

Tags: python

Here's a demonstration of what I mean:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 10**(5)
100000
>>> 10**(-1/5)
0.1
>>> 10**(-1/6)
0.1
>>> 10**(-1/100)
0.1
>>> 10**(-1/19325)
0.1
```

It is able to calculate positive powers and negative integers, but when I put in a negative fraction, it consistently returns 0.1.

I've also tried using the Fraction() object, but the same issue occurs.

Comment: Why don't you just print the exponents?

Comment: On Python 2, the `/` operator performs *integer division* on two `int`s

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the boilerplate at the top would suggest so :P

Comment: Try `10**(-1/5.)` the `5.` is a `float`, so it does what you expect.

Comment: @TemporalWolf heh, you're right!

Comment: Cheers - had a bit of a moment there